# Difference between verb + よう and verb + ように

Tags: grammar

I was reading the definition for 請う{こう}

> (明鏡国語辞典)　ある物を与えてくれる（また、ある事をしてくれる）ように相手に願い求める。
> (大辞泉)　他人に、物を与えてくれるよう求める。また、何かをしてくれるよう願う。

My translation of definition from 明鏡国語辞典:

> To ask/request someone to give something (or do something) to/for you.

I think that ように here means along the lines of "such that…".

The definitions are very similar but I noticed that the definition from 大辞泉 has よう followed immediately by a verb (願う). The definition from 明鏡国語辞典 use structure ように.

Is there any difference between よう and ように? I.e. would something like 何かをしてくれるよう願う and 何かをしてくれるように願う mean something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 何かをしてくれるよう願う

I would say that an accurate translation would be: "To ask so that someone does something for you".

The くれる in してくれる means something like "to give me the act of (you) doing something" -> "to do something for me" and not "to give me something".

Concerning your main question, I don't understand it either but it's definitely 様 so maybe に is simply omitted. I have looked for examples of よう願う and よう求める and it seems to be a set form used at formal settings meaning "so that".